# How to get data and show it to my Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

How to get the data under foods (product Name)?

I can get the data (with the check icon).
I want to get the data from the wrong icon.

[image]

Here is my `MainActivity` code for database reference

```java
    // getting Firebase Database reference to communicate with firebase database
    private final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // creating List of MyItems to store user details
    private final List<MyItems> myItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // getting RecyclerView from xml file
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        // setting recyclerview size fixed for every item in the recyclerview
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // setting layout manager to the recyclerview. Ex. LinearLayoutManager (vertical mode)
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // clear old items / users from list to add new data/ users
                myItemsList.clear();
                // getting all children from users root
                for (DataSnapshot Requests : snapshot.child("Requests").getChildren()) {
                    // to prevent app crash check if the user has all the details in Firebase Database
                    if (Requests.hasChild("askfor") && Requests.hasChild("tablet") && Requests.hasChild("total")) {
                        // getting users details from Firebase Database and store into the List one by one
                        final String getaskfor = Requests.child("askfor").getValue(String.class);
                        final String gettablet =Requests.child("tablet").getValue(String.class);
                        final String gettotal =Requests.child("total").getValue(String.class);
                       // final String getproductName =Requests.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
                        // creating user item with user details
                        MyItems myItems = new MyItems(getaskfor, gettablet, gettotal);
```

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: apparently I'm missing a code to get the data of productName under foods and that's what I need.

Comment: What is the exact code you are talking about?

Comment: The above code is my code that can get the value of askfor,tablet and total under Requests (see image for ref) and what I'm currently lacking is the code on how to get the data under foods tab which is the productName value.

Answer (score 0):

The `foods` node in your database looks like an array, so if you get its value in Java code you'll get a `List`.

So you can loop over the food children just as you do already for the requests children:

```
if (Requests.hasChild("foods") {
  for (DataSnapshot foodSnapshot : Requests.child("foods").getChildren()) {
    String productName = foodSnapshot.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
    ...
  }
}
```

---

Unrelated: since your `onDataChange` implementation on seems to process the `Requests` node, it is more efficient to only load that node from the database, instead of loading the entire database.

So:

```
               //  Add here
databaseReference.child("Requests").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // clear old items / users from list to add new data/ users
        myItemsList.clear();
        // getting all children from users root
                                         //  Remove here
        for (DataSnapshot Requests : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            ...
```